# Можно ли в web.xml определить сервлет без указания url-pattern и если да, то как к нему обратиться?

Tags: java

Можно ли в web.xml определить сервлет без указания url-pattern и если да, то как к нему обратиться?

Comment: Мне кажется, Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос.

Comment: Вы конечно же можете вообще не определять сервлет в web.xml с помощью аннотации @WebServlet но url всё равно придётся указать.

Comment: Какая версия сервлета?

Comment: предполагается использовать 2.5